# error when running trinidad from shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trinidad-gem

I am using rvm to manage ruby versions. Also I am making use of trinidad. When I run `trinidad -e production` from any path then it runs but when I ran it through the shell script then it given the error

```
Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'trinidad' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s)
  to_specs at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:298
   to_spec at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:309
       gem at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47
           at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13/bin/trinidad:22
      eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101
    (root) at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:15
```

Comment: Answer: rvm x.x.x do trinidad -e production . Thanks to @maxd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rvm x.x.x do trinidad -e production` in your script or specify default rvm ruby version use `rvm use x.x.x@global --default`.

**Update**

Probably you problem can be related to current rvm gemset. So, try to specify ruby version with and without `@global`.

Comment: Try to specify bundler: `rvm x.x.x do bundler exec trinidad -e production`

Comment: Same error. Dont know what I am doing wrong.I tried some other rvm use to. Its not working. It still given error only when running from shell script

Comment: Do I need to import any rvm paths in shell script?